# Layering two map plots with Python matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, maps

I'm looking to layer two maps (identical outlines & axes) on the same plot, so I can then use a slider to alter the alpha value of the top map to see the differences in the choropleth between each layer.

```
def Slide(AlphaVal):

    CrimeMap.plot(column='Burglary', scheme='equal_interval', k=9, colormap=plt.cm.Blues, alpha=0.2, linewidth=0.5, axes=ax)

    CrimeMap.plot(column='Anti-social behaviour', scheme='equal_interval', k=9, colormap=plt.cm.Blues, alpha=0.2, linewidth=0.5, axes=ax)
    return(plt.show())

interactive(Slide, AlphaVal=(0.0,1.0))
```

This just seems to plot one layer, even though I have set transparency on both (AlphaVal will be used on the top layer).

How would I go about getting both layers on this plot?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Define a variable as a figure, and then plot each map into the figure using the variable. Then, simply return plt.show(Var) as below:

```
def Slide(AlphaVal):

    CrimeMap = plt.figure(figsize=(12,12))

    CrimeMap = RozzersMap.plot(column='Burglary', scheme='equal_interval', k=9, colormap=plt.cm.Reds, alpha=0.2, linewidth=0.5, axes=ax)

    CrimeMap = RozzersMap.plot(column='Anti-social behaviour', scheme='equal_interval', k=9, colormap=plt.cm.Blues, alpha=AlphaVal, linewidth=0.5, axes=ax)

    return(plt.show(CrimeMap))

interactive(Slide, AlphaVal=(0.0,1.0))
```